# Daylight savings time and JavaScript timezone conversions

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I have this dilemma with JavaScript. I need to convert a list of dates from client's local timezone to NYC (EST) timezone. I'm using the function below:

```
Date.prototype.toNycTime = function() {

    var localTime = this.getTime();
    var localOffset = this.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    var utc = localTime + localOffset;
    this.setTime(utc - 3600000 * 5);

    return this;
};
```

It works OK. One problem is that I need to adjust UTC offset every time there's a daylight saving switch in USA. And that works OK for any date that is before the next switch (earliest coming is 13-MAR-2011). But it doesn't work on dates after the switch. I don't know of any build-in JS function in any of the browsers that will do the conversion for me.

Is there a good library out there that will allow me to do some universal conversions? Or can anyone offer any tips on the code above? I'm trying to avoid programming in the dates/times for the conversion and having to look up all the time.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

http://www.datejs.com/

> Datejs is an open-source JavaScript Date Library.
>
> Comprehensive, yet simple, stealthy and fast. Datejs has passed all trials and is ready to strike. Datejs doesn’t just parse strings, it slices them cleanly in two.

Comment: It fails dealing with daylight saving time.

Comment: Seems that DST is an issue in Javascript. A quick google search shows several viable options, but they're rather long functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with this exact problem... corporate users throughout the world, but 'corporate time' is PST/PDT which includes daylight saving time.

How I've been approaching it:
I actually parse a POSIX timezone string for PacificTime starting with

```
PST8PDT,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2
```

and reformat those into parseable date strings for when clocks more forward and back.
Using the hours-offset embedded in the TZ string, I convert the forward and back times to epoch timestamps and use an if-then to calculate if corporate time is currently DST.

This yields an offset from UTC I can use to convert local 'epoch' times (which are already in UTC) to a conceptual localtime (that is actually converted in UTC time, but looks local).

I have to do this as 'flot' does everything in UTC